# Sternum pain after dips, other upper-body exercises

Tags: pain, upper-body-workout

I'm wondering how best to treat/avoid a sharp sternum pain I get after I do dips or other upper-body exercises. I'm a male, 30 years of age, and it's happened a few times over the past 6-8 months. I've never felt this sensation before. I've noticed a fairly sharp pain dead-center of my chest, right on/under my sternum after I do upper-body workouts. It usually lasts a couple days and then goes away, but in the meantime it's painful to sneeze, cough, or take deep breaths.

I'm not sure the best way to treat or avoid it, or if it's just a form of muscle soreness that will go away with increased strength in my chest and shoulders. Any ideas?

Comment: There are quite a few articles about "sternum pain after dips." A common cause are strained muscle tendons attached to the sternum.

Comment: Welcome to Physical Fitness!